# Spring MVC Framework issues with multi module Maven project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, multi-module

My apprication has the following structure. When I basically move `Room.java` to the library module (of course setting the include paths accordingly), the application builds and so on, but cannot be started with Spring (`mvn spring-boot:run -pl application`).

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roomController': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.kehrwasser.agilecasino.multimoduleapplication.RoomController] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@55054057]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
```

What kind of issue is it and how can I resolve it?

Project structure:

```
.
├── application
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── java
│           │   └── com
│           │       └── kehrwasser
│           │           └── agilecasino
│           │               └── multimoduleapplication
│           │                   ├── DemoApplication.java
│           │                   ├── Room.java
│           │                   └── RoomController.java
│           └── resources
│               └── application.properties
├── library
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   └── java
│       │       └── com
│       │           └── kehrwasser
│       │               └── agilecasino
│       │                   └── multimodulelibrary
│       │                       └── service
│       │                           ├── MyService.java
│       │                           └── ServiceProperties.java
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── com
│                   └── kehrwasser
│                       └── agilecasino
│                           └── multimodulelibrary
│                               └── service
│                                   └── MyServiceTest.java
└── pom.xml
```

Comment: please show the pom files best would be having a project on Github etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise Sure, check the Gitlab repo: https://gitlab.com/dielok-personal/agile-casino-backend/-/tree/master You'll find the moved approach in one of the two feature-branches.